# Detecting versions of Opera Mini Extreme Mode with Javascript

Tags: android, opera-mini

It seems that "Extreme Mode" in Opera Mini is different from device to device, even with the same Opera Mini version background-size (for example) works on the iPhone with Extreme Mode, or on the Opera Mini Java emulator app, but not on Android 5 with Extreme Mode.

I've looked at the official documentation (https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-and-javascript/) but it does not provide information on this.

I would like to be able to differentiate between these obviously different modes.

Right now I'm using this script to detect Opera Mini modes, but `isOperaExtreme` is true both for the iPhone and Android. I want to use text fallback for when background size doesn't work.

```js
// start opera detect
// Check if current browser is Opera
var isOpera = window.opera | window.opr | ( navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') > -1 ) | ( navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' Coast/') > -1 ) | ( navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPiOS/') > -1 );

// Check if the Opera browser is Opera Mini or Opera Mobile in regular mode (called High Savings Mode)
var isOperaHigh = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR/') > -1) && (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mobile') > -1) && (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Presto/') < 0);

// Check if the Opera browser is Opera Mini in Extreme Savings Mode
  var isOperaExtreme = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera Mini/') > -1) && (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Presto/') > -1);
// end opera detect

$('#opera-detection-1').html('isOpera: ' + isOpera);
$('#opera-detection-2').html('isOperaHigh: ' + isOperaHigh);
$('#opera-detection-3').html('isOperaExtreme: ' + isOperaExtreme);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="opera-detection-1">

</div>
<div id="opera-detection-2">

</div>
<div id="opera-detection-3">

</div>
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I went around it, I didn't detect the browser at all, in my particular case all I needed was to create compatibility for the images in my website, I use SVGs but I also needed fallback to PNGs for old Android browsers. Opera mini also does not support background size for SVGs, so I though I could use detection for all that. I ended up not using SVGs as backgrounds, and just using "onerror" to switch to PNG: `<img class="top-bar-icon" src="images/svg-images/icn_phone_white.svg" onerror="this.src='images/svg-images/fallback/icn_phone_white.png'; this.onerror=null;" alt="">`

Comment: that might be a good way to swap images. I'll give it a try. thanks a lot.

Comment: there's also an "gulp svg2png" plugin that converts svg to png so you don't have to manually do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.operamini` field. It's [legal](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-and-javascript/).

`window.operamini` available only in extreme mode(full compression), because without full compression Opera Mini uses default browser engine. High Savings Mode just effects on content like images, video and etc.